# Marginal probability in case of $4$ variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have $4$ variables $R,S,C,W$ which take binary values and I have to find $P(S=1)$. All probabilities are given below.

[image]

According to my understanding of marginalization the answer should be $$P(S=1 \mid C=0) + P(S=1 \mid C=1) = 0.6.$$ The solution also uses marginalization, but it considers all the other variables as well.

Comment: this pains me to visualize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not account for the probability that $C=0$ and $C=1$.

We have

$$\begin{align*}
P(S=1)
&=P(S=1 \cap C=0) + P(S=1 \cap C=1)\\\\
&=P(S=1|C=0)P(C=0)+P(S=1|C=1)P(C=1)\\\\
&=\left(0.5\cdot0.5\right)+\left(0.1\cdot0.5\right)\\\\
&=0.3
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I applied the marginalization rule incorrectly. Thanks a lot man!